# General vs Model-specific observers and mailers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, actionmailer

When creating mailers and/or observers do you organize them based on models or based on their task?

#### based on models

```
PictureMailer
PictureObserver
EventMailer
EventObserver
UserMailer
UserObserver
```

#### or based on tasks

```
AdminMailer (Mails to be sent to admins)
AdminObserver 
NotificationMailer
NotificationObserver
```

Answer (score 1):

I organize them based on their tasks. I prefer having more, small, fine-grained mailers over a few, larger, coarser-grained ones. For example, I'd probably not have `AdminMailer`, but a couple of different mailers for different things that happen in the admin. Same goes for notifications - you probably have more than one use case that sends notifications, so I'd have a mailer for each. Generally, one can think about it as mailer-per-feature.

As for the observers, it depends on their task. If I'm monitoring creating and modifying of users for analytics, I'll probably have just a single `UserObserver`. I'll rename it to `UserAnalyticsObserver` as soon as I need a second observer on user. Looking at a current project, I have four observers and only one of them is named after the model - most are named after the feature.

My reasoning here is following the Single Responsibility Principle, which essentially means that one class should have one reason to change. If I go with naming mailers/observers after the models, I end up with classes that support multiple features, thus, multiple reasons for change.